# IONIC CAPACITOR APP IonApp classname is undefined instead of platform

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I added ionic and capacitor to react.js  app. ion-app classname should be ios or android but it is undefined. Anyone knows that how to solve?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ozd5.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error when i run their template app using `ionic start`. To overcome the problem, I did this

`ionic start your-first-app tabs`

This creates a similar template app with tabs. However, Unlike the template app that you get by running `ionic start` and then selecting `my-first-app` as the starter template, you dont get the gallery app code